# Relationship between AWS Cognito User Pool and Identity Pool

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

How are the items in the user pool and the identity pool linked? How can I lookup the Cognito `identityId` based on Cognito user `sub`? How can I lookup the Cognito user `sub` based on Cognito `identityId`? Also, I currently use the Cognito `identityId` as user ID for identifying users across my app, should I use `sub` instead?
If I want to delete a user due to account cancellation, should I remove the `identityId` as well?

I use the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Just a note for anyone using DynamoDB. If you want to use fine grained IAM access, you can only use the identityID from the identity pool. The sub value from the user pool won't work.